# How is it possible to convert/write a .yml file into a .h5 file?

Tags: python, yaml, h5py

I am trying to write/convert a .yml file into a .h5 file. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you clarify why you need to convert it? Maybe start by showing examples of what input and output you expect?

Comment: Hi, i use dark sky API to extract some hourly data like temerature and preciption prob and am currently writing them to a .yml file, but i need to convert and have them in h5 format to use

Comment: Have you tried looking at hdf5 python examples? Any questions you have on those? Don't try to convert formats, just write to both